# `svnadmin upgrade` producing error on `db/min-unpacked-rev`

Tags: svn, svnadmin

I'm attempting to upgrade a repository to allow mergeinfo/merge-tracking support

`svn: E200007: Retrieval of mergeinfo unsupported by 'svn+ssh://server/repo'`

I shell into the SVN server, and run:

> svnadmin upgrade ./repos/svn/

```
Repository lock acquired.
Please wait; upgrading the repository may take some time...
svnadmin: E000017: Can't open file 'repos/svn/db/min-unpacked-rev': File exists
```

Command run as root; `repos/svn/db/min-unpacked-rev` owned by root